# Error "invalid byte sequence for encoding UTF8" on insert into BYTEA

Tags: postgresql

is there any  pair of encrypt and respective decrypt function?
Functions In PGCRYPTO library uses hash algorithms so they don't have decryption functions.
Also when I am using pgp_sym_encrypt() and pgp_sym_decrypt() functions,
pgp_sym_decrypt() function gives the above error for encrypted value of pgp_sym_encrypt().
I am using Postgres Plus Advanced Server 8.4.
Do I have to put \ before every escape sequence character or what?

Please provide the solution how to access bytea data and also put encrypted value in 
table column and decrypt the same value.
Thanks
Tushar

Comment: Would help if you shared some code.

Answer (score 1):

If you encrypt/decrypt binary data you should use `pgp_sym_encrypt_bytea` and `pgp_sym_decrypt_bytea` functions.

The functions `pgp_sym_encrypt` and `pgp_sym_decrypt` are for textual data which has to be encoded in client encoding and possible to convert to database encoding. So you can not use them for example to encrypt images, PDFs etc.